# Class members and interrupts

Tags: c++, class, microcontroller, volatile, interrupt-handling

I have a class `Pass` that has 4 variables and two methods:

```
class Pass{
private:

int a = 0;
int b = 1;
int c = 2;
int d = 3;

public:

void increment(){
    a ++;
    b +=2;
    c += 5;
}

void echo(){…} // flush vars to output
}
```

In the `increment()` method, three variables are incremented. Every 2 seconds, an **interrupt routine is called** in which the **`increment()` method is called**. Do I have to declare these variables as `volatile`?

P.S. Yes, it is a pseudo-class for MCU.

Comment: Are we talking about `c` or `c++`? There is no `c++` tag here. Seeing `c` and `class` tag together makes no sense.

Comment: I don't think you need volatile unless you have more than one thread modifying the variables at once and you have other portions of code reading the values and depending on them being exactly accurate.

Comment: @TarekD, You right.

Comment: No need for volatile here. As `increment()` is called from another thread, it would make sense to add memory fence after updating the variables so the changes would become visible (e.g. cache line is invalidated).

Comment: @Todd, This is the code for the AVR microprocessor.  Timer every 2 seconds calls `pass.increment()` and in the main loop the values ​​of all member Pass class variables are sent to UART by `pass.echo()`.

Comment: `pass.echo()` runs in an infinite loop without pauses.  But every two seconds it is interrupted by the Interrupt routine from the Timer.  The `echo()` function is ATOMIC.

Comment: This [question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/20994/why-the-need-to-use-the-volatile-keyword-on-global-variables-when-handling-inter) might also help.

Comment: Thank you for the link but I know what the `volatile` is for.  My current code declares member variables without the keyword `volatile` and works without a problem.  But I would like to know if it is, for C ++, the right keyword for a member variable to have.  I was looking for it on the internet and on the stackoverflow, I found some answers, but they didn't answer my question.

Comment: This is an interesting question. I assume you've read over the wikipedia explanation of volatile. If your running your code as a debug build (not optimized) and it works, and if you do a release build and it doesn't, then it's safe to say that you do need the volatile keyword.

Comment: if you want a variable that you can ensure that you have the exact value of in a time critical way... maybe you want to declare it as "register" ?

Comment: I have 12 nights here now.  I go to sleep.  tomorrow, I'll try to compile the code with different optimization settings.

Comment: If your loop that sends the values of the variables to the UART doesn't modify these variables and your loop depends on them to know when to stop looping... they perhaps you do need volatile. Because the compiler will see your loop checking the value but not see anywhere within your function a change being made to them.. it optimize your loop to not check the values.. infinite.

Comment: @Todd, keyword register on AVR platform?

Comment: @Todd, Yes, I just think it's dangerous.  I feel bad about it, so I look for an answer.  I'm going to try different optimization settings tomorrow and write down how it went.

Comment: My code is [here] (https://github.com/colesnicov/IRQSwitch), if someone cares.

Comment: Yeah. I don't know if register would be effective or relevant. The compiler may or may not even regard it.

Comment: I have tried different types of optimization:
`-O0` = 13,463 bytes flash, 1144 bytes ram - no problem.
`-01` = 3859 bytes of flash, 962 bytes of RAM - no problem.
`-O2` = 3785 bytes of flash, 962 bytes of ram - no problem.
`-O3` = 4725 bytes of flash, 962 bytes of RAM - no problem.
`-Os` = 3609 bytes of flash, 962 bytes of ram - no problem.
`-Og` = 4753 bytes of flash, 992 bytes of ram - no problem.
`-Ofast` = 4725 bytes of flash, 962 bytes of RAM - no problem.
Everything works fine. So now I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

So, after a lot of testing, I figured it didn't have to.  I don't use the keyword 'volatile' in my classes and everything works as it should.  I think it is, in this case, just a question of a moral approach.  Maybe I should write it there, but because he basically didn't answer my question during all that time.  so here is my answer: If I write it there, I will not spoil anything.

Comment: If you think this question has no value, then delete your answer, then delete the question. And do it quickly, before someone else adds an answer which prevents you from deleting the question.

Comment: Its no matter. I dont use keyword 'volatile' and its work fine.

Comment: otherwise I would probably leave it here if someone was looking for it ..

Comment: `volatile` did not help on a full featured OS running on a hardware with caches and multiple cores! And that you can not see that the program has UB is no evidence that the program has no UB. If you have really no mcu running and a single core only, than `volatile` is ok.